# MPI_Gather of columns

Tags: mpi

I have an array which is split up by columns between the processes for my calculation. Afterwards I want to gather this array in one process (0).

Each process has its columns saved in array A, process 0 has an array F for collecting the data. The F-array is of size n*n, each process has part_size columns, so the local arrays A are n*part_size. Columns are sent to alternating processes - c0 goes to p0, c1 to p1, c2 to p0 again and so on.

I created new datatypes for sending and receiving the columns.

On all processes:

```
MPI_Type_vector(n, 1, part_size, MPI::FLOAT, &col_send);
MPI_Type_commit(&col_send);
```

On process 0:

```
MPI_Type_vector(n, 1, n, MPI::FLOAT, &col_recv);
MPI_Type_commit(&col_recv);
```

Now I would like to gather the array as follows:

```
MPI_Gather(&A, part_size, col_send, &F, part_size, col_recv, 0, MPI::COMM_WORLD);
```

However the result is not as expected. My example has n = 4 and two processes. As a result the values from p0 should be in columns 0 and 2 of F and p1 should be stored in 1 and 3. Instead both columns of p0 are stored in 0 and 1, while the values of p1 are not there at all.

```
0: F[0][0]: 8.31786
0: F[0][1]: 3.90439
0: F[0][2]: -60386.2
0: F[0][3]: 4.573e-41
0: F[1][0]: 0
0: F[1][1]: 6.04768
0: F[1][2]: -60386.2
0: F[1][3]: 4.573e-41
0: F[2][0]: 0
0: F[2][1]: 8.88266
0: F[2][2]: -60386.2
0: F[2][3]: 4.573e-41
0: F[3][0]: 0
0: F[3][1]: 0
0: F[3][2]: -60386.2
0: F[3][3]: 4.573e-41
```

I'll admit that I'm out of ideas on this one. I obviously misunderstood how Gather or Type_vector works and saves their values. Could someone point me in the right direction? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have re-posted the answer. before it was messy/wrong - sorry for that but now sorry for being so huge..... :P hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that I see is that the datatype created with `MPI_Type_vector()` has extent going from the first to the last item. For example:

The extent for your `col_recv` datatype is between `>` and `<` (I hope this representation of the mask is clear enough):

```
>x . . .
 x . . .
 x . . .
 x<. . .
```

That is 13 MPI_FLOAT items (must be read by row, that's C ordering).
receiving two of them will lead to:

```
>x . . .
 x . . .
 x . . .
 x y . .
 . y . .
 . y . .
 . y . .
```

That clearly is not what you want.

To let the `MPI_Gather()` properly skip data on the receiver you need to set the extent of `col_recv` as large as exactly *ONE ELEMENT*. You can do this by using `MPI_Type_create_resized()`:

```
>x<. . .
 x . . .
 x . . .
 x . . .
```

so that receiving successive blocks gets correctly interleaved:

```
   x y . . 
   x y . . 
   x y . . 
   x y . .
```

However receiving two columns instead of one will lead to:

```
   x x y y
   x x y y
   x x y y
   x x y y
```

That again is not what you want, even if closer.

Since you want interleaved columns, you need to create a more complex datatype, capable of describing all the columns, with 1-item-extent as before:

Each column is separated (stride) as one ELEMENT (that is the *extent* - not the size, that is 4 elements - of the previously defined column):

```
  >x<. x .
   x . x .
   x . x .
   x . x .
```

receiving one of them per processor you'll get what you want:

```
   x y x y
   x y x y
   x y x y
   x y x y
```

You can do it with `MPI_Type_create_darray()` as well, since it allow to create datatypes suitable to be used with the block-cyclic distribution of [scalapack](http://acts.nersc.gov/scalapack/), being your one a 1D subcase of it.

I have also tried it. Here is a working code, on two processors:

```
#include <mpi.h>

#define N      4
#define NPROCS 2
#define NPART  (N/NPROCS)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  float a_send[N][NPART];
  float a_recv[N][N] = {0};
  MPI_Datatype column_send_type;
  MPI_Datatype column_recv_type;
  MPI_Datatype column_send_type1;
  MPI_Datatype column_recv_type1;
  MPI_Datatype matrix_columns_type;
  MPI_Datatype matrix_columns_type1;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  int my_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

  for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
    for(int j=0; j<NPART; ++j) {
      a_send[i][j] = my_rank*100+10*(i+1)+(j+1);
    }
  }

  MPI_Type_vector(N, 1, NPART, MPI_FLOAT, &column_send_type);
  MPI_Type_commit(&column_send_type);

  MPI_Type_create_resized(column_send_type, 0, sizeof(float), &column_send_type1);
  MPI_Type_commit(&column_send_type1);

  MPI_Type_vector(N, 1, N, MPI_FLOAT, &column_recv_type);
  MPI_Type_commit(&column_recv_type);

  MPI_Type_create_resized(column_recv_type, 0, sizeof(float), &column_recv_type1);
  MPI_Type_commit(&column_recv_type1);

  MPI_Type_vector(NPART, 1, NPROCS, column_recv_type1, &matrix_columns_type);
  MPI_Type_commit(&matrix_columns_type);

  MPI_Type_create_resized(matrix_columns_type, 0, sizeof(float), &matrix_columns_type1);
  MPI_Type_commit(&matrix_columns_type1);

  MPI_Gather(a_send, NPART, column_send_type1, a_recv, 1, matrix_columns_type1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (my_rank==0) {
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
      for(int j=0; j<N; ++j) {
        printf("%4.0f  ",a_recv[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: after the effort for explaining... a comment if unclear or an upvote would be really welcome :(

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I was planning on getting back to you and once again forgot about it. Thanks for the help!