# Different MPI_Datatypes for Sender and Receiver

Tags: c, mpi

With MPI, can data be sent and received with different MPI_Datatypes that are derived from the same base type and have the same total length?

Consider two MPI processes **A** and **B**. **A** has an array `double a[n]` and **B** has an array `double b[m]`.  Both processes know that **A** wants to send **B** `k` doubles that are somehow distributed in `a` (only **A** has knowledge about this distribution). **B** (and only **B**) knows how it wants to arrange the `k` doubles in `b`. So both create (via `MPI_Type_indexed` and `MPI_Type_commit`) a datatype that for **A** corresponds to the elements it wants to send from `a` and for **B** corresponds to the locations it wants to save these elements to in `b`. **A** calls `MPI_Isend(a, 1, A_datatype, ...)` and **B** calls `MPI_Irecv(b, 1, B_datatype, ...)`.

Does this work? If yes, is this the standard way to solve the problem at hand? If no, how is such a data exchange commonly done?

Comment: You want to transmit k double values, with k known to both A and B. Where is the problem?

Comment: **A** wants to transmit `k` `double` values to **B** that are non-continuously arranged in memory in both processes. Additionally, the data layout of these `k` `double` values is different for both processes.

Comment: Are the layouts related, i.e. can A/B compute its layout given B/A's layout, or are they independent? From the way you worded the question it seems they're unrelated. If they are unrelated, then your problem is you want to transmit `k` values, a very straightforward task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it works, and it's quite a standard way to solve it.

The datatype is just *instruction on how to pack data* at the sender side, and *instruction on how to unpack them* at the receiver one.

This is a very useful and a very standard approach with MPI-IO.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! From what you say, I assume that the actual message a MPI implementation sends around does not (or at least does not have to) contain any type information but is only interpreted in a certain way by the receiver based upon the datatype specified at the receiver's end. Is that correct?

Comment: you correctly asserted in the question "derived from same base type", and the example was ok. The answer is *yes* keeping it valid. In fact in principle MPI can work across hosts of different architectures, say little endian XF86's and big endian ARM's (just an example): MPI should correctly interoperate swapping the bytes of an MPI_INT for example (of the underlying MPI native datatype in general). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831431/mpi-gather-of-columns/21833674#21833674) is an example I have posted - see whether you can find it useful

Answer (score 2):

MPI types in matching send and receive operations have to be *congruent*. Congruency is a weaker form of equivalence. It means that the two datatypes might not be equal but their type signatures must match.

Each MPI datatype is a list of tuples in the form `(offset[i], basic_type[i])` where `offset[i]` is the offset of the `i`-th item in bytes from the beginning of the data buffer (it could also be negative) and `basic_type[i]` is the language datatype of the item. The list of those tuples is called the type map. The list of basic types alone is called the signature of the type.

Imagine that you declare an indexed datatype with 5 blocks of one element each:

```c
// Data type 1
MPI_Datatype type1;
int b_lens[5] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
int b_offs[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7 };

MPI_Type_indexed(5, b_lens, b_offs, MPI_DOUBLE, &type1);
```

`type1` has the following type map: *{ (8, double), (16, double), (24, double), (40, double), (56, double) }* and a type signature of *{ double, double, double, double, double }*.

Now a different contiguous type is created with the same number of basic elements:

```c
// Data type 2
MPI_Datatype type2;

MPI_Type_contiguous(5, MPI_DOUBLE, &type2);
```

`type2` has the following type map: *{ (0, double), (8, double), (16, double), (24, double), (32, double) }*. This type map is obviously not the same as the one for `type1` because the offsets are different. But the type signature is the same: *{ double, double, double, double, double }*. Therefore `type1` and `type2` are said to be congruent.

The following piece of code is a perfectly valid MPI program:

```c
double array1[10];
double array2[5];
double array3[10];

if (rank == rank_sender)
{
  MPI_Send(array1, 1, type1, rank_receiver, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Send(array1, 1, type1, rank_receiver, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else if (rank == rank_receiver)
{
  MPI_Status status;
  int num_elems;

  MPI_Recv(array2, 1, type2, rank_sender, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  MPI_Recv(array3, 10, MPI_DOUBLE, rank_sender, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_DOUBLE, &num_elems); // num_elems will be set to 5
}
```

The `MPI_Send` call will pick the 1-th, 2-nd, 3-rd, 5-th, and 7-th elements of `array1` at the sender and the `MPI_Recv` call will place them in the contiguous 5-elements array `array2` at the receiver. Also a 10-element receive with the original datatype `MPI_DOUBLE` is congruent with the datatype of the sent message, though only the first 5 elements of the buffer will be filled in. A call to `MPI_Get_count` with a datatype of `MPI_DOUBLE` will then return `5`.

Basically, congruency of both types means that the same number of data items of the same basic type(s) and in the same order are packed into and then unpacked from the message.

The MPI standard requires this congruency in correct applications. But in reality many MPI implementations do not transmit the type signature within the message and therefore the congruency is never enforced. For example, both Open MPI and MPICH allows you to use `MPI_DOUBLE` on the sender side and `MPI_LONG` (assuming an LP64 system) on the receiver side. The two datatypes are of the same size in bytes, but converting the `double` into `long` is meaningless. There are run-time MPI correctness checking tools like [MUST](http://tu-dresden.de/zih/must) that can detect such problems in the code.

Comment: Thank you for introducing and explaining the concept of congruency so well!